# Laravel Passport: Wrong token JSON response

Tags: php, laravel, http-status-codes

I am using `Laravel 5.7` + `Passport 7.2`.

My API route is as follows

```
// namespace "App\Http\Controllers\Admin"
Route::namespace('Admin\Api')->group(function () {

    // test route
    Route::get('test', function(){
        Return 'hello test';
    })->name('login');

    // unauthorized routes
    Route::post('authorizations', 'Auth\AuthorizationsController@store');

    // authorization routes
    Route::middleware(['auth:api'])->group(function () {

        // User controller
        Route::namespace('Users')->group(function () {
            // get user detail
            Route::get('user', 'UserController@me');
        });

        // Rbac controller
        Route::namespace('Rbac')->group(function () {
            // get tree menu list
            Route::get('menu/select', 'MenuController@select');
        });

    });
});
```

When I tried to request `/api/user` with a wrong or empty token, I got a redirect. However, in the case of pure API, errors such as 401 should be reported: TOKEN error, not 302.

How to solve this situation?

Comment: who do you request `/api/user`? from browser??

Comment: I can't understand what you mean. My API may be available for view layer views like Android, IOS APP or React. Front and rear separation

Comment: sorry typo i mean *how

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you doesn't provide valid token in protected route laravel recognize as a Unauthorized and if you request it without define `Accept` header it will redirect to **login** page, if you define `Accept` headers to be json it will response **401** status with **Unauthenticated** message.

So the solution it add `Accept:application/json` in your request headers.

example with axios (javascript)

```
axios({
  method: "GET",
  url: "api/user",
  headers: { Accept: "application/json" }
});
```

Comment: I tried using `{ Accept: "application/json" }` and the problem was solved. But it seems that a new problem has arisen.
thank you very much

Comment: @noecs if my answer solve your problem, please accept it.